# External USB Hard Drive not turning off after Windows 10 shut down

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

It seems my External USB drives don't power off completely after a Windows 10 shutdown.

I think this is due to fast boot.

Is it safe to remove or should I always eject prior to shut down?

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to remove/disconnect because no writing is happening and the reason why they don't power down completely is not related with *fastboot* but with the USB ports power settings that may or may not be controlled by the firmware (BIOS/UEFI).

Comment: I hear a loud click prior to shut down but the drive still runs any idea on the noise?
If I eject there is no loud click.